# Form Validation is not working using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

My Form is not sending data to the mysql database.
please help me.
I have 2 files/
1 file is enroll.php and the second 1 file is db.php.
I have designed my whole form and php validation on the same file.
but its not sending the data to the database.
can someone help me to solve this issue.

i have this code
Page: enroll.php

````
<?php
session_start();
require ('admin/db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    
    $query= "INSERT INTO `tbl_students` (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `cnic`, `course`, `gender`, `mobile`, `email`, `date`, `address`) VALUES ('', '$fname', '$lname', '$cnic', '$course', '$gender', '$mobile', '$email', '$date', '$address')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
        if($query_run){
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Data Submitted Successfully";
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['status'] ="Values not Correctly inserted";
        }
}
?>
   

<!-- Enrollment Form -->
<div class="container">
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" name="cnic" type="text" placeholder="Enter your CNIC" required>
<br>
 
<select class="form-select" name="course" aria-label="Default select example" required>
  <option selected>Select Course</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="form-select" name="gender" aria-label="Default select example" >
  <option selected>Select Gender</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile Number" required>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="dateofbirth" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="dateofbirth" required>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required ></textarea>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){
    echo "<h4>" .$_SESSION['status']. "</h4>";
    unset($_SESSION['status']);
}
?>

</div>```
<!-- Enrollment Form -->


Page: db.php
```<?php
    
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","studentenrollment");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>```
[Output of the Form In this Image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IsWO.png
````

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), it will tell you why it is failing. If `id` is implemented properly (integer, not null), then you cannot send an empty string. If it's set to autoincrement, then just remove the id from the insert string and your database will handle it properly

Comment: i checked my database, id is implemented as integer and set to auto increment. i also tried to remove id from the INSERT string but still not working......

Comment: Use the error handling and check the error. Remove `id`, and '', from the insert query.

Comment: You have to share the MySQL code too